# Разбивка строк на подстроки в C#

Tags: c#

Есть строка, содержащая слова, перечисленные через запятую.

```
string fruits = "апельсин, мандарин, лимон";
```

Как наиболее просто получить из этой строки массив подстрок с этими словами?

```
string[] fruit = { "апельсин", "мандарин", "лимон" };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Comment: Если быть точным, то так

string[] fruit = fruits.Split(new char[] { ',' });